# Why do fluoride ions "win" over thiocyanate ions in a solution with iron ions?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, equilibrium, aqueous-solution

When you mix aqueous iron(III) nitrate and potassium thiocyanate together you get a red solution. Then if you add sodium fluoride, the red colour disappears.

This is basically because the $\ce{Fe(SCN)^2+}$ ions are red, but $\ce{FeF^2+}$ ions are colourless.

I get Le Chatelier's principle in that, the more iron ions that are stolen by the fluoride, the less $\ce{Fe(SCN)^2+}$ ions there will be because they keep dissociating etc.

The thing I wonder about is why the fluoride atoms get all the iron. I can think of a couple of potential reasons for this, but I don't know which, if any of them, are true, even after googling a fair bit.

Could it be the case that iron is a lot more attracted to fluoride than thiocyanate? Or that the fluoride reaction isn't reversible? And if either of those is true, can this experiment be seen as evidence for that?

Comment: Well, I guess Fe(III) (aq) is "hard" enough to prefer F- from SCN-

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the MEL science website (https://melscience.com/US-en/articles/fake-chemical-cut/)

> "Adding sodi­um flu­o­ride de­stroys the iron(III) thio­cyanate com­plex­es, and col­or­less hex­aflu­o­ro­fer­rate(III) [FeF₆]³¯ ions form. Fe(CNS)₃ + 6NaF→Na₃[FeF₆] + 3NaC­NS"

Seems that it may create this hexafluoriferrate ion instead... just thought I'd add to this discussion. I was actually just trying to find out a bit more about this reaction myself. AP Chem teacher here :)